# Removing a list of users from a group and silently failing on specific entries

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the need to cleanup data between a database and an Active Directory.
To make the whole architecture simpler, let's just say that in my database, I have a list of groups, and their members.

In my AD, I also have groups, but I need to cleanup the memberships of these groups to be the same as the one in my database.

I came up with a simple solution that is to compare the list of members in my database with the one in my AD group, then make a differential to know which accounts I need to remove from the AD group, and which accounts I need to add to the group.

The problem is that the volume of users in my whole environment is pretty big and cause latency issues. During the treatment of the differential, the script failed with the error :

```
Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADException : The specified account name is not a member of the group
```

After some debugging it showed that in the duration of the script, some operations continue to run on AD and the database, and the member was removed from that group after the differential was established, causing the script to try to remove again that member of the group, causing the error. Due to the volume of users, the time between the differential and the end of treatment of that differential can be several hours.

Is there a way to silently fail for this entry, and this entry only, and continue to process the list of users, when the command is formatted as follow ?

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $users -Server $ADServer  -Credential $creds -Confirm:$false
```

We cannot realistically check the membership of the group between each operation to update the differential because the treatment time would be exponentially higher.

Also, related question, would that silent failing work when the account doesn't exist in AD anymore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a list of group members to `Remove-ADGroupMember` it removes either all of them, or none (if for instance an error occurs). To be able to ignore non-existing users you need to remove each member individually, e.g. like this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$users | ForEach-Object {
  Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $_
}
```

Note that on the Windows 2008 R2 DC where I tested this I had to set `$ErrorActionPreference`. Adding the parameter `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to `Remove-ADGroupMember` did not work.

The other option you have is to enumerate the group members first, and remove only those that are present:

```
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group |
           Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName |
           Where-Object { $users -contains $_ }

Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $members -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: While this is an answer to my biggest problem, I'm not sure about the performance. I have over 300k users in 70k groups. Do you have any idea about the time difference between the batch command that I'm using now and your solution approximately ? I imagine that sending one command per operation will be significantly slower. The current script is already taking up to 4 days to run, I'd be extremely grateful if you can provide me with an information that would avoid me running the script and benchmark it (especially if it goes to run for weeks after the modification).

Comment: You basically have 2 options: a) check which members are present, then remove just those with a single call, or b) remove one member at a time while ignoring errors. Take your pick.

Comment: Addendum: you may be able to improve performance by pushing the list of changes to a DC and running the commands locally instead of invoking all commands remotely.

Comment: I'm actually using the a) solution, but the time between checking the users and treating the result of that check is too large, and then that checklist is outdated by the time I go to process it. I'll go for b) since there's no other solution for what it seems. I'll just wait before accepting your answer in case someone comes up with a miracle solution.

Comment: You don't need to check all users for solution a), only the current members of the group (see bottom half of my answer).

Comment: Yes I understood that, but if I have let's say 100k users in a group, by the time I checked that the first one is member of the group, until I checked the last, an operation could have deleted the membership of that user, causing the error. It's a kind of concurrency issue.

Answer (score 0):

for all built-in cmdlets powershell provides some  [Powershell common parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx)  which allow you to exercise control over what happens when an error occurs.

in your case you would want to :

```
remove-adgroupmember -identity something -members something -erroraction silentlycontinue
```

and i would strongly recommend using the built in ad cmdlets. If you are using your own function to remove group members then you have to wrap your code in a [try catch block](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx)

Comment: I edited my question to reflect the actual powershell cmdlet. I was also under the impression that using -erroraction silentlycontinue would let the script continue, but still stop the actual command at the entry where it failed. Am I wrong ?

Comment: in theory `silentlycontinue` should do exactly that which is process a list of items and when an error occurs ignore the error and move on to processing the next item on the list but i havent exactly tested this...anyway do check out the answer posted by @ansgar below maybe that would work for you.

Comment: @Kiran Failed statement is failed. `SilentlyContinue` allows your script to proceed with the next statement. It doesn't make the current statement "partially not fail".

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers .. In the following command would it be correct to say the command partially failed or partially succeeded?....`Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -ComputerName compdoesnotexist,compexists -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: Let's not waste our time on sophistery. `Get-WmiObject` makes a connection to each individual computer and collects the results. `Remove-ADGroupMember` does not remove each member individually, but either all or none.